# Is there a way to get the device node of a usb device using libusb APIs?

Tags: linux, libusb

I am trying to get the device node (eg. /dev/sdb) of a usb device.

I was wondering if there is any libusb API that would give me the particular device node to which the USB device is associated with.

If there is no API, are there any other alternate means of achieving this? Any insight on this would prove REALLY helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, easiest method to explore attached USB devices and their properties is to simply scan directory `/sys/bus/usb/devices`. This virtual directory lists all attached devices. Each entry has very simple structure, and for every device that has slave connected (like device connected via hub) there is virtual subdirectory.
What is also nice that in general you do not need to be root to read a lot of device properties, like manufacturer or serial number.

Another very good property of this interface is that it is semi-stable. That is, every device has unique id like `a-b.c.d.e:x.y` (a - bus number, b,c - root hub, next hub, port, etc.., x,y - function, subfunction), and this device enumeration is not going to abruptly shift for all devices if one device is connected or disconnected.

You can also easily map these device ids into libusb-style bus/device numbers (but those are not stable).

Unfortunately, this is Linux specific, and does not seem to be available for other operating systems. I wish libusb had implemented something like this, but it does not.
Anyway, good luck!